# Condition in array_push using php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Here is my php code:

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orders2 = $order['line_items'];
    $lineitemcount=0;
    foreach($orders2 as $lineitem) { 
        array_push($list, array($order['name'],$order['email'], $order['financial_status']));
        $lineitemcount++;
    }
}
```

Here I want to add,condition for array_push. i.e., if `$lineitemcount>0`, the values contained in `array_push` should be print, else empty.

I don't know where is fix my issue.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you want to print $list if $lineitemcount>0 ?

Comment: If you want empty in else part, where should `array_push` go?

Comment: @ Awlad Liton: Yes:).

Comment: @ asprin: I get the values as csv file, so in else part, array_push go to empty  field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? ;oP

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
  $orders2 = $order['line_items'];
  $lineitemcount=0;
  foreach($orders2 as $lineitem) { 
    if ($lineitemcount>0) array_push($list, array($order['name'],$order['email'],
$order['financial_status'])); // "print in array $list"

    if ($lineitemcount>0) print_r(array($order['name'],$order['email'],
$order['financial_status'])); // print as an array

    if ($lineitemcount>0) echo implode("\n",array($order['name'],$order['email'],
$order['financial_status'])); // print as lines

    $lineitemcount++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.can you tell me without using print_r?.. because i get the value as .csv file.

Comment: yes, I've edited : print_r(array) becomes echo implode("\n",array) ;oP

Comment: I want to use array_push, I got error from your code, and i can't get the values. Can you help?. Thanks :)

Comment: I've edited, can you give the error message, what is `$list` ?

Comment: sorry, $list[] = array('Name','Email','Financial status');
$list = array_filter($list);

Comment: Can you help to write add if-else condition within that array_push?.

Comment: I've edited, so you want to "print" (put) in the $list array, I've just put the condition before, so you don't need to show what is pushed in the array?

Comment: I m asking to add if condition for array within that array_push. i.e, if $lineitemcount>0, i should get array($order['name'],$order['email'],
$order['financial_status']) else empty. Did you get my question? Thanks :)